# Populate input type textarea with static content (without ajax call)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a textarea in my html page and I wish I could do this:

```
<textarea id='myTextArea' src='data.txt' />
                          ==============
```

Unfortunately I can't do that. "src" does not work for a textarea.

So I have to recur to some javascript to make an ajax call (http get for data.txt) and then populate myTextArea.

Is ajax the only way to resolve this ?

Many Thanks

Comment: an input type=textarea does not exist use something like <textarea name="textarea"  cols="35" rows="35"> message</textarea>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<script>

function loadFile()
{
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xmlhttp.open("GET","foo.txt",false);
xmlhttp.send();
var value = xmlhttp.responseText;
document.getElementById("myTextarea").value=value;
}

</script>
```

And html:

```
   <body onload="loadFile()">

     <textarea id="myTextarea" cols="20">

    </textarea>

   </body>
```

Comment: @Michael that's really great but it's an AJAX call (and pretty much what I have done) I was wondering if there is an easier solution... if nobody posts something else I will tag you as the correct answer thanks

Answer (score 3):

A better option might be to output the content of that file via a server-sided language. Since the content in static, the extra HTTP request isn't really necessary.

In PHP, you could do it like this:

```
<textarea id='myTextArea'><?php include "data.txt" ?></textarea>
```

Edit: As Quentin noted, you may want to parse the included file before injecting it into the HTML, especially if the file included can easily be modified by a third party. Functions like `htmlspecialchars` can be used to validate the file content accordingly:

```
<textarea id='myTextArea'><?php htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents("data.txt")); ?></textarea>
```

Comment: That's dangerous. You need to read in the data then escape it with `htmlspecialchars`.

Comment: @JeffreySweeney that's an interesting option... but my html pages are static (they are not templates)

Comment: @Zo72 So you don't have access to any server-sided technologies? If that's the case, then AJAX is the only option.